How to pull constantly changing values from one cell and store them as a log book in excel on daily basis?
I have been provided with dynamic cell A1 inside workbook1 sheet1, which updates with temperature value once a day. I need to keep a log of monthly temperature variation and store it inside another workbook2 sheet2 column B across Column A that contains prefilled Dates (for example from 1-May-2024 to 31-May-2024). How can accomplish that using excel formula inside column B to avoid manual copying and pasting? I already know VBA version , I need easier way with formulas and logic.
Example.
Inside A1 cell dynamically changes value (lets say today 1-May-2024 temperature[20], but tomorrow 2-May-2024 temperature will show [25])
"Workbook1
Sheet1 ( 1-May-2024)"
Cell: A1 - Today shows value "20"



ColumnA
ColumnB




20




"workbook1 Sheet1 (2-May-2024)" Cell: A1 - Tomorrow shows value "25"



ColumnA
ColumnB




25




"What I need is to show in Workbook2, Sheet2 TODAY"



Dates
ColumnB




1-May-2024
20


2-May-2024




"I need in Workbook2, Sheet2 TOMORROW"



Dates
ColumnB




1-May-2024
20


2-May-2024
25



And so on. I need this workbook2 to update automatically when I open it. I intend to open it once a day everyday. Without VBA help.

You can't do this with a formula.

In your post you said you don't want a vba solution but workbook_open event can run the macro to check for a record for today's date and if it doesn't exist make one, and if the cell next to it is blank, then open the other file and take the value. Formulas won't simplify copying and pasting the cell.

Can't do much without the specifics, but I'd recommend workbook_open to find and check the last cell of your range if it's today's date. If it's not, add it one row below that row, then pull in the value from your workbook. This would run as you open the file, just need to give it the OK so it should eliminate the manual effort of copy and paste

Yeah i managed to do it with VBA, but my workbook is very heavy as it is, about 5 MB and adding VBA slows it down even more. I was checking to see if there is an [IFS] statement that can do it. For example =IF(B2=TODAY(),A1,null), but that deletes the previously recorded value. Thanks for suggestions anyway.

I'm afraid BigBen is right

Probably you have different problems if your file is that big + slow.
